# Как получить значение выбранного input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, jquery-form

Народ, помогите пожалуйста. Делаю калькулятор стоимости ремонта. Использую jQuery. Полей много, приведу пример одного из них, на котором нужно разобраться. Не понимаю, почему переменная radio111 не получает значение, а undefined.

```
<input type="radio" id="kbut" value="2150" name="radio111">
                    <label for="kbut" style="margin-right: 40px">Квартира</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="taunbut" value="2200" name="radio111">
                    <label for="taunbut">Коттедж/Таунхаус</label>


$('.formclass input').change(function(){
    var radio111 = $('input[name="radio111"]:selected').val();
    console.log(radio111);      
});
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас чекбокс ведь. `:checked`.

```
$('input').change(function(){
   var radio111 = $('input[name="radio111"]:checked').val();
   console.log(radio111);      
});
```

Comment: Иногда и так бывает, что даже смешно)) Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @PolonskiyP если вам помг ответ, буду благодарен, если отметите его верным.

Comment: так отметил (стрелочкой вверх, полезен)

Comment: @PolonskiyP там под стрелкой вниз есть галочка , при нажатие на которую вы отметите ответ таким, который помог вам решить вашу проблему.  [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) . Это полезно, если в будущем какой-то пользователь будет иметь пролему как и у вас, он может быстро понять для себя, какой из ответов подошел лично вам (и, возможно, ему). Посмотрел ваш профиль по вопросам... Вам предстоит много работы)